# C++: Why does dereferencing this vector iterator segfault?

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator, segmentation-fault

```
void insert_string( std::vector<std::string> & strings, const std::string &s )
{

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it=lower_bound(strings.begin(),strings.end(),s);
    if(strings.size()>0) std::cout<<*it<<" is found\n"; // ****
    strings.insert(it,s);
}
```

When attempting to use this function, the first insertion goes fine. The second insertion will output "[firststring] is found" and then segfault. If I comment out the if/cout line, I can repeatedly call and no segfaults occur.

I've also tried doing something like `std::string tmp=*it;` which will then segfault on that line. While printing is not a huge deal, what I'm really trying to do is check if the string at the position found by lower_bound is the same as the string that is trying to be inserted (i.e., `if(*it==s)`, which is segfaulting just like the above two examples).

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: surely you mean `if (it!=strings.end()) std::cout <<*it<<" is found\n";` ?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used the word "found"; I just wanted to print what the value that the iterator ended up at was, not trying to imply that the string `s` is actually found in this vector (although that is ultimately what I want to do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check for the condition if `it == strings.end()`, if it is don't print it. This could cause the issue. Are you sure the string you're trying to check is in the vector of strings?

Comment: Ah, this is precisely the issue. When inserting, I do not know whether or not the new string is in the vector of strings already; in fact, if it is, I don't want to add it. Adding in a check to see if the iterator was the end of the vector fixed my issue. Thanks!