# Bad access on reading vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a `vector<int>` called `pitches`. I'm getting periodic `bad access` on the last line below:

```
int play = 0;
bool didFind = 0;
vector<int>::const_iterator iterator;

for (iterator = pitches.begin(); iterator != pitches.end(); ++iterator) {
    if (*iterator > lastpitch) { // lastpitch is an int
        didFind = 1;
        play = *iterator;
        break;
    }
}

if (!didFind) play = *(pitches.begin()); // this line gives me bad access
```

I had previously tried `*pitches.begin()` on the last line but that always provided bad access and I understand that now. But while I get it less often now, this `play=*(pitches.begin());` is still doing the same occasionally. I cannot see anything in the above that would cause that, any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Is the vector empty at that point, perhaps? (In particular, taking into account that `didFind` is false there.)

Comment: A note on style: it's generally preferable to use true/false instead of 1/0 when dealing with `bool`s.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598621/c-why-does-dereferencing-this-vector-iterator-segfault

Comment: Another note on style: just use `std::find_if`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `pitches` vector has size `0`, the things inside

```
      for (iterator=pitches.begin();iterator!=pitches.end();++iterator)
```

doesn't get executed and therefore `didFind=0`.

The statement inside `if` is evaluated. Yet `pitches` is empty means `pitches.begin()==pitches.end()`. Dereferencing a `pitches.end()` is to access out of bound and therefore gives `bad access`.

Comment: I'll debug but I'm quite certain the vector is never empty. I'll find out shortly, thanks.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns then add a `assert(pitches.size())` before all these sequence to check.

Comment: Indeed there was an isolated case when the vector could be empty.